# I have defined a macro in .netrc file but when I execute it from ftp it says "macro not found"

Tags: ftp

Here is the .netrc file and the command I use, any idea what is wrong here?

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /root/.netrc
machine ftp.nyxdata.com
login anonymous
password empty

macdef download_nyse_index
cd /OpenBook/SymbolMapping
bin
get SymbolMap.xml /tmp/SymbolMap.xml
quit

[root@localhost ~]# ftp
ftp> $ download_nyse_index
'download_nyse_index' macro not found.
ftp> bye
[root@localhost ~]# uname -a
Linux localhost 3.17.8-200.fc20.i686+PAE #1 SMP Thu Jan 8 23:45:44 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
[root@localhost ~]# which ftp
/bin/ftp
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qf /bin/ftp
ftp-0.17-65.fc20.i686
```

Comment: AFAIU, macros have to be executed with the `$ macroname` syntax..

Comment: This is the way I execute it `$ download_nyse_index`

Comment: Ah sorry! Missed that somehow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `macdef` directive, like the others (`login`, `password`, etc.), only applies to the `machine`-headed stanza that it's in. As far as I know, putting a `macdef` directive before the first `machine` stanza has no effect, and there's no way to have a macro available before the `open` command is executed.

Your macro will work if you open a connection to the site first:

```
$ ftp ftp.nyxdata.com
ftp> $download_nyse_index
```

To script a full FTP session, pass input to the `ftp` command.

```
ftp ftp.nyxdata.com <<EOF
cd /OpenBook/SymbolMapping
bin
get SymbolMap.xml /tmp/SymbolMap.xml
quit
EOF
```

If you're doing something this simple, use wget or curl. If you don't want the password to be on the command line, you can put in in `~/.netrc`; wget reads it by default, and curl reads it if you pass the `-n` option.

```
wget -O /tmp/SymbolMap.xml ftp://ftp.nyxdata.com/OpenBook/SymbolMapping/SymbolMap.xml
```

Comment: For some reason `wget` didn't work earlier but now it does so this is the solution I used

Comment: So, I cannot have a macro that does `open a-very-long-server-name.com`?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger Not in the classical `ftp` command, AFAIK. But there are many other FTP clients.

Answer (score 1):

Using `strace ftp` on my fedora, it didnt even read `~/.netrc` unless I ran it with a hostname on the command line.

Also, it didnt recognise the macro until I explicitly added a blank line after it, at the end of file!  So try

```
$ ftp ftp.nyxdata.com
ftp> $download_nyse_index
```

Comment: I used `strace` too to find out that the `ftp` command didn't read the `.netrc` file. I think that while reading about `.netrc` I saw that this file is read during the login, like `.bashrc` etc`